# SQL query getting multiple where-claused aliases

Tags: sql

Hoping you can help with this issue.

I have an energymanagement software running on a system. The data logged is the total value, logged in the column Value. This is done every hour. Along is some other data, here amongst a boolean called `Active` and an integer called `Day`.

What I'm going for, is one query that gets me the a list of sorted days, the total powerusage of the day, and the peak-powerusage of the day.

The peak-power usage is counted by using Max/Min of the value where `Active` is present. Somedays, however, the `Active` bit isn't set, and the result of this query alone would yield NULL.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    A.Day, A.Forbrug, B.Peak
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Day, Max(Value) - Min(Value) AS Forbrug
     FROM 
         EL_HT1_K 
     WHERE 
         MONTH = 8 AND YEAR = 2016
     GROUP By Day) A, 
    (SELECT 
         Day, Max(Value) - Min(Value) AS Peak
     FROM 
         EL_HT1_K 
     WHERE 
         Month = 8 AND Year = 2016 AND Active = 1
     GROUP BY Day) B
WHERE 
    A.Day = B.Day
```

Which only returns the result where query B (Peak-usage) would yield results.
What I want, is that the rest of the results from inner query A, still is shown, even though query B yields 0/null for that day.

Is this possible, and how?

FYI. The reason I need this to be in one query, is that the scada system has some difficulties handling multiple queries.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Sample data and desired results can really help explain why you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want conditional aggregation.  Based on your description, this seems to be the query you want:

```
SELECT Day, SUM(Value) as total,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Active = 1 THEN Value END) as Peak,
FROM EL_HT1_K
WHERE Month = 8 AND  Year = 2016 
GROUP BY Day;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was going for, thank you very much. 

I will accept the answer in 6 minutes, when SO allows me to.